# Best JavaScript framework for desktop applications

Tags: javascript, desktop-application, javascript-framework

There are similar questions but none seems to hit the mark. I am looking for feedback on developing a desktop application using a JavaScript framework. Here are some details to remove confusion between a desktop-like web application and a true desktop application:

1. It needs to run entirely standalone. There are lots of discussions about JavaScript frameworks for web development but this is strictly a desktop application (using WebKit probably) which narrows the field of contenders.
2. Needs to run on Windows, Linux and Mac at least.
3. For performance it needs to communicate with threaded native code - C++ probably. The QtWebKit Bridge would be a possibility. This may not influence the framework used.
4. The UI needs to have a rich set of layouts and controls just as in a native desktop app, as well as charting and custom graphics.

Some contenders include Adobe AIR, Ext JS and Dojo/Dijit. Ext JS 4 was recently released with a MVC architecture that looks very attractive and may change previous comparisons of frameworks.

I am looking for feedback from others who have experience developing desktop apps like this and strengths and weaknesses they have encountered with different frameworks.

Comment: It's not clear whether you need a JS framework or a Desktop application framework that's coded in JS.

Answer (score 2):

There is so much time that you have posted this question, but i answer for those who will read this topic.

Now, you can use [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) by **Atom** to create your desktop app (**Slack** is built with electron)

Or, you can use [AppJS](http://appjs.com/) as an alternative.